# Is it possible to reserve a seat for Deutsche Bahn ICE using a vending machine while booking a ticket?

Tags: seating, deutsche-bahn

I will be travelling from Frankfurt using an ICE and for some reason online booking is not an option.

Is it possible to reserve a seat using the ticket vending machine?

I really want to avoid the extra fees of visiting the *Reisezentrum* and also I need a seat maybe beside the luggage rack and don't know the German word for it :(

Comment: Do you mean seat only or ticket+seat?  Do you already have a ticket?

Comment: Ticket+seat is what I meant.

Comment: I can’t find an online source whether booking *just* a reservation costs more in the Reisezentrum than online/mobile/at the machine. I’ll try to remember to ask next time I’m close to or in a Reisezentrum.

Comment: There are no fees in the Reisezentrum anymore for long distance tickets. Only for some special regional fares you pay a fee (like for the Länderticket etc.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can buy a ticket with a seat reservation, or just a seat reservation (if you already have a ticket) at the ticket machines.

Unless the booking process has been changed recently, you are however not able to choose where to sit, but will simply be assigned a free seat. So, you will not be able to get a seat guaranteed close to a luggage rack.

Comment: Thanks :) Is it somehow guaranteed that a ticket for 2 people will have seats together?

Comment: @Jeet.Deir If adjacent seats are available, I would expect so.

Comment: @Jeet.Deir The German [online FAQ](https://www.bahn.de/q?s=faq%7Cpk%2FDEU%2Fde&q=Sitzplatzreservierung&l=de&c=DEU&dc=%E2%99%A5) states: ‘If you are travelling with multiple people, we generally try to give you adjacent seats according to your choices. In rare cases it may happen that a train is so fully booked that no close seats are available. This will be shown by a red warning under the seat reservation details. In all cases, the seats will be within the same car. You always get to choose whether you want to accept those seats or take a different train.’